# Сортировка и сохранение порядка по строкам в базе

Tags: php, mysql, сортировка

Задача следующая:
Есть таблица с товарами допустим их 1000, на странице выводится по 100 товаров.
Я хочу поменять их порядок и вывести на первой странице **НЕ** 1-й, 2-й, 3-й и тд.
А допустим 15-й, 107-й, 1-й, 502-й и тд.
Вопрос в следующем как сохранять их порядок в базе(приоритеты|order_by_id|еще как то) при большом количестве перестановок и как отслеживать эти перестановки?

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос. вы уже определились, что вам нужно отдельное поле, где будет хранится номер для сортировки. ок. дальше то в чем проблема?
они же не сами по себе у вас передвигаться то будут. Переместили одну запись с позиции `i` вверх на позицию `j`, значит все что было от `j+1` до `i` включительно надо увеличить 1.

Comment: @teran сложность в том что бы избежать перезаписи всех значений при изменении порядка у нескольких элементов. И при добавлении нового товара.

Comment: дак вот вы и опишите этот конкретный пункт в вопросе вашем. а то так далее ответов и не увидите в вопросе, счас в нем нет конкретики.  у вас там миллиард товаров что ли, что перезаписывать нельзя номера? тем более не у всех, а у части только какой то, разве что вы в начало всегда будете добавлять новый товар. но если стратегия именно такая, то можно в обратном порядке нумеровать.